# Wifi not working in Acer Aspire 4752G with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, acer, atheros

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire 4752G and I can't get wifi working.

My wifi controller is:

```
 giovanni@giovanni-Aspire-4752:~$ lspci | grep Network
 03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter  (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Based on this (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k) I enabled the ath9k module with modprobe ath9k

This got the phy1 wifi device to show up:

```
giovanni@giovanni-Aspire-4752:~$ rfkill list 
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

But it seems hard blocked. I can't find any hardware switch on the laptop and there is no option to enable/disable it in the BIOS either.

```
giovanni@giovanni-Aspire-4752:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 7c:e9:d3:08:70:55
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.13.0-26-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:f3a00000-f3a0ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:6a:8a:6a:cd:1d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=192.168.0.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f3800000-f380ffff memory:f3810000-f381ffff memory:cfa00000-cfa007ff
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: According to the manual, it is Fn+F3.  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, but Fn+F3 only turns the soft blocked on/off

Comment: May we also see: `lsmod | grep acer`

Comment: giovanni@giovanni-Aspire-4752:~$ lsmod | grep acer
acer_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,acer_wmi
video                  40960  2 acer_wmi,i915

Comment: Does it help to do: `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi` followed by: `sudo rfkill unblock all` and then: `rfkill list all`?

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, but thank you for your help